# Spring rest api by-passing authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have a module named "abc" which has security feature for user authentication

and username and password is authenticated with ldap server

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
<authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedLdapAuthenticationProvider" />

<ldap-server id="ldapServerIDGreenBus" url="${ldap.URL}/${ldap.Base}"
    manager-dn="${ldap.Username}" manager-password="${ldap.Password}" />
```

I am intercepting url pattern for all users who have any role.

**Problem:** I have a **forgotpassword service** built in this module which is before the user sign-in therefore no role has been defined and I am taking only email from user so that I could change the password and send it to user's main address.

Therefore, I tried two things

**1.**`<intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" access="permitAll"/>`

**Result:** Failed because permitAll does authenticate but it allows all pattern provided they must have a authentication object(username and password).

**2.** `<http pattern="/forgotPassword" security="none" />`

**Result:** Failed and checked in postman and it showed this

[image: securityAuthError]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define permissions in a SecurityConfig file as well with an overridable 'configure' method.  I would try something like this.  I added the 'forgotPassword' url matching below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/forgotPassword/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER") 
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()          
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successForwardUrl("/loginSuccess")
            .failureUrl("/loginError")
            .permitAll()                
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}

}
```

Comment: there is no difference between <intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" access="permitAll"/> and what you did ????

Comment: Please answer in alternate xml config since I have configured in that...

Comment: There is a difference in the URL pattern itself.

Comment: I have replaced my url with  "/forgotPassword/**" in corresponding xml but still not working

Comment: I was using "/forgotPassword" intercept after "/**"(this has role defined) therefore Overriding